# initializing Netlogo without setup (running headless with R)

Tags: python, r, netlogo, headless

I have a model that needs to update one specific value for all the patches before every run. After each timestep, these values change are updated (via an external model).
This means, the Netlogo model has to run and then stop (make a break), I need to output some data, then I need to update the patch values and then run Netlogo again. I would like to run one R script to setup the Netlogo model, then run another similar R script to run the go function in Netlogo. However, currently, 
-   I close the R script which is performing the Netlogo `setup`, 
-   then I try to run another similar R script with the `go` function (without `setup`) – then this second script doesn’t execute

Does anyone have experience on how to initialize Netlogo through R without running `setup`? In other words, I am trying to specify the initial conditions without a speed-up run (without the `setup` part) – is this possible and if yes then how? Even though I wrote about R, this is not a necessity. I could also use the python interface, but I need to use some interface without GUI, as this needs to run on a terminal. The fundamental question is how to specify initial conditions for a run.

So here is example of R code:

---

### # for set up the model

```
# load RNetLogo package
library(rJava)
library(RNetLogo)
require(RNetLogo)
nl.path     <- "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NetLogo 5.2.0"
# the path to the NetLogo model file
model.path  <- "......\\veg_model_1.nlogo"
#Load specific model
my.netlogo <-"veg_model_1.nlogo"
NLStart(nl.path, gui=F, nl.obj=my.netlogo) #Creates an instance of NetLogo.
NLLoadModel(model.path,nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLCommand("setup", nl.obj=my.netlogo) #Executes a command 
NLQuit(nl.obj = my.netlogo)
```

---

### # to update value and run go for 1year

```
# load RNetLogo package
library(rJava)
library(RNetLogo)
require(RNetLogo)

# an R random seed (for beeing reproducible)
set.seed(-986131948)

nl.path     <- "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NetLogo 5.2.0"

# the path to the NetLogo model file
model.path  <- ".......\\veg_model_1.nlogo"
#Load specific model
my.netlogo <-"veg_model_1.nlogo"
NLStart(nl.path, gui=F, nl.obj=my.netlogo) #Creates an instance of NetLogo.
NLLoadModel(model.path,nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
# here is the value i needed to update
NLCommand("Setpatchwaterpotential", nl.obj=my.netlogo) #Executes a command 
Command("go", nl.obj=my.netlogo)
NLQuit(nl.obj = my.netlogo)
```

---

### ## in Netlogo the setup and go:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks 
  setup-globals
  setup-patches    ; Init patches, init Hydroregime
  setup-individuals
end

to Setpatchwaterpotential
   'read input files'
end

to go
  ifelse ticks = 0
  [
    Setpatchwaterpotential      
    ......          
    tick           ;to count timesteps (ticks) = how often did the model 
  ] 
end

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of you have taken a look at the RNetlogo package for R. You can find examples in the paper from [Jan C Thiele in JSS](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v058i02). For me, your problem is not a `setup` problem, you can run what you want and interact with the model as you want...

In R with `NLCommand()` you can send to netlogo exactly what you want.

```
NLCommand("set timeV ", 255)
```

The go procedure can be a loop so you can `go` step by step. As exemple :

```
j <- 1
for(i in 1:2000){
    NLCommand("go")
    if(j == 10){
      pos.agents <- NLGetAgentSet(c("who","xcor", "ycor","size","color","stockCoopSugar",
                                    "plocsugar","ticks"), "turtles")
     }
}
```

Each 10 step, I keep track of my agents layout
I hop it helps

Comment: Hi, i have saw that paper and understand your said to run go by looping it. However, my problem is that i run once setup-go1year-quit R and netlogo, at second year i have to create exactly same patch and turtle values from last time step. I have tried with output all the values that needed to setup the model and use as input files for next time step, however, using the mode 'setup-go1year-quit-updatedby NLCommand (create conditions of last time step at year 1 and update one patch value)-go-1yearquite', does not give the same results by using 'setup-go2years-quit'.

Comment: Can you use the markdown command to express what is `code` and what is commenting ? Give use an example of what append in both case `setup-go1year-quit-updatedby` and once `setup-go1year-quit`? For that edit your question

Comment: Hi, I have added the R code and Netlogo, hope this time my queston is more clear

Comment: From my point of view, I would rather read  files in R. In that way you can load a matrix and load it in the netlogo space and  so on...